# How to move text from one web form text box to another web form text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to load text from one text box in my Admin Web Form, to my Home Page web form text box

I have tried this code but I literally can not get it working since my admin class will not detect the control from the other web form..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Session` variables to transfer text (or data) from one page to another.

In the source page, you save the data in the `Session` variable:

```
Session["HomeText"] = txtHomeEntry.Text;
```

In the destination page, you load the save text:

```
txtHome.Text = (string)Session["HomeText"];
```

You can use additional `Session` variables (e.g. `Session["AboutUs"]`) to transfer the other data.

Comment: I spent hours looking for the solution, thanks very much you've helped me more than you can imagine!!